# How to get multiple locations of multi touch UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a UITapGestureRecognizer in my view and I can get the location of its touch with below code fine. Now if I change this recognizer's number of touches to 2 (or more), it still gives me one location. How can I get two locations of the two touches?

```
tapGesture.locationInView(self.view)
```

Kindly help in swift.

Comment: Did you check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708184/handle-taps-in-two-different-points-at-a-same-time-via-uigesturerecognizer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `locationInView`, use `locationOfTouch` to get the location of each tap:

```
let tapLocation1 = tapGesture.locationOfTouch(0, inView: self.view)
let tapLocation2 = tapGesture.locationOfTouch(1, inView: self.view)
```

Comment: thanks thats what worked. @Mehdi that you for the right direction

Answer (score -3):

Try switching on the `multipleTouchEnabled` property of your custom view

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {

        self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: how does this answer the question?